# Producing multiple builds signed with different keys from single build type

Tags: android, gradle, code-signing

I am using Gradle to build my Android project, with the default debug and release build types. I want to produce two APKs based on the release build type, signed with different keys. One would be for testing, and the other would be for the actual Play store. Alternatively, I want to generate both a signed and unsigned build.

I know I can modify the signing config of the release build type with the following:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        myConfig1 {
            ...
        }

        myConfig2 {
            ...
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig ...
        }
    }
}
```

How can I specify two signing configs, and/or have gradle produce both signed and unsigned builds?

One thing I have tried is making a new build type and calling initWith(buildTypes.release). I then specified a different signing config there. The problem is that it rebuilds the entire app for every build type, which I want to avoid, if possible.

Answer (score -1):

Just create two different release build types, one for each signing config.

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        myConfig1 {
            ...
        }

        myConfig2 {
            ...
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.myConfig1
        }
        release2 {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.myConfig2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This causes the project to be built once for release and once for release2. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: No. Another way would be to not have any signingConfigs at all which will generate an unsigned apk which you can then sign either manually or through some custom tasks defined in build.gradle.