# Gradle signing flavors with different keys on Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, code-signing

I have many flavors of my Android app, and *I want all but one to use the same key*. There is one that needs to use a different key.

**How do I override the `signingConfig` for just 1 flavor of the app (but within the same build type e.g. "release")?**

- I would like all builds by default to use the main release configuration.
- I only want to *override 1 flavor*
- I want to be able to run all release builds with a single `gradlew assembleRelease` command

This last point is important as I currently have over 120 different flavors and growing. In order to customise every single flavor individually is a lot of extra work.

---

Related posts I have tried:

[Producing multiple builds signed with different keys from single build type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17825595/383414)

- this requires configuration for each flavor
- it doesn't seem to use my custom `signingConfig` anyway

[Signing product flavors with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17074660/383414)

- accepted solution doesn't work (for me)
- according to [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040494/signing-product-flavors-with-gradle?rq=1#comment33498762_17044746) this is possible by putting `buildTypes` inside the `productFlavors` but I do not understand how to do this.

[Debug Signing Config on Gradle Product Flavors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26579662/383414)

- as explained on blog post: [Building Multiple Editions of an Android App with Gradle](http://blog.robustastudio.com/mobile-development/android/building-multiple-editions-of-android-app-gradle/)
- <strike>it doesn't work</strike> actually it **works perfectly**
- but it doesn't scale well for 119 flavors

Overall, each solution seems to still use the default release config, instead of my custom config.

---

Important parts of my `build.gradle` look like this:

```
signingConfigs {
    releaseConfig {
        storeFile file('key')
        storePassword "pass"
        keyAlias "alias"
        keyPassword "pass"
    }

    custom {
        storeFile file('custom_key')
        storePassword "pass"
        keyAlias "alias"
        keyPassword "pass"
    }
}

productFlavors {
    apple {
        applicationId "demo.apple"
    }
    banana {
        applicationId "demo.banana"
    }

    // def customConfig = signingConfigs.custom
    custom {
        applicationId "custom.signed.app"
        // signingConfig customConfig
    }
 }


buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
    release {
         signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
         // productFlavors.custom.signingConfig signingConfigs.custom
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is as simple as finding the place in the documentation where this is explained - I have not found the documentation for Gradle particularly good.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing question and answer! I see that you maintain ~120 flavours now with huge build times. I'm in the same boat of creating a while label app which has to be re-branded numerous times. I'm just starting. I've to use different keys for signing each flavour though but there are other UI & config changes. Do you have any suggestion on how you maintain such a huge project architecture / config wise, what to look out for or what you would do differently if you could start from scratch now? It would be great topic for a blog post if you have time to share ;). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-Flavor-Configuration) says that you can:

> have each release package use their own `SigningConfig` by setting each
>   `android.productFlavors.*.signingConfig` objects separately.

This is demonstrated in this answer ([Debug Signing Config on Gradle Product Flavors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26579662/383414)) and this blog post ([Building Multiple Editions of an Android App with Gradle](http://blog.robustastudio.com/mobile-development/android/building-multiple-editions-of-android-app-gradle/)).

However, specifying a separate `signingConfig` line for each flavor does not scale well, and was out of scope of the question. Unfortunately none of the provided answers showed how to correctly override a `signingConfig` correctly.

---

The trick came from this answer ([How to get the currently chose build variant in gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29479208/383414)) which shows how to loop over build variants (and by extension, flavors).

My solution uses a loop to set the `signingConfig` on each flavor instead of having a separate line for that. This scales perfectly well. The "override" is done with a single line that specifies the custom config after the loop.

Place the following code inside the `buildTypes.release` block:

```
// loop over all flavors to set default signing config
productFlavors.all { flavor ->
    flavor.signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
}
// override default for single custom flavor
productFlavors.custom.signingConfig signingConfigs.custom
```

Comment: That's unfortunate you had to jump through such hoops to get it to work. It seems counter to their documentation to have to iterate on the variants and look for a flavor by string name.  Although... `productFlavors.all` is actually a common script block to use, but I wasn't sure you could switch the `signingConfig` there.  Especially because they showed a sort of example without that.  But I'm glad you found a solution!  And thanks for posting it back.

Comment: Love this, this simplifies what I have right now as well.

Comment: Just a note that order is important in build.gradle -- productFlavors {} and signingConfigs {} must be declared before buildTypes {}. There is no such order requirement otherwise.

Comment: This is not correct, release{} buildType will override previous declared buildType blocks then, this way only release{} signing keys will be used

Comment: Things may have changed since 2015 when this was posted - feel free to post an updated answer @Jemshit. This question and answer came from a 100% production project, doing daily builds of debug & release build types. At the very least, back in the day, this worked 100% from my personal experience of using it.

Answer (score 19):

The below given code will use release1 as default signingConfig if signingConfig is not specified in the product flavor.

app/build.gradle

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file("/home/.../debugkeystore.jks")
        storePassword "..."
        keyAlias "..."
        keyPassword "..."
    }
    release1 {
        storeFile file("/home/.../testkeystore1.jks")
        storePassword "..."
        keyAlias "..."
        keyPassword "..."
    }
    release2 {
        storeFile file("/home/.../testkeystore2.jks")
        storePassword "..."
        keyAlias "..."
        keyPassword "..."
    }
    release3 {
        storeFile file("/home/.../testkeystore3.jks")
        storePassword "..."
        keyAlias "..."
        keyPassword "..."
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.signingproductflavors"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release1
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug { 
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}

productFlavors {
    blocks {
        applicationId "com.example.blocks"
        resValue 'string', 'APP_NAME', "Blocks"
    }
    cloud {
        applicationId "com.example.cloud"
        resValue 'string', 'APP_NAME', "Cloud"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release2
    }
    deck {
        applicationId "com.example.deck"
        resValue 'string', 'APP_NAME', "Deck"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release3
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the simple elegance, but would it work? How would you build a `debug` build with a different key in this case? I like the idea of using a `defaultConfig` but won't that override all build types?

Comment: Yes, this code works. Properties of product flavors override the properties of default config. Default config does not override build types. You can use debug { signingConfig signingConfigs.release3 } in buildTypes to define different signing config for debug build type.

Comment: So how would the code look: 1) all debug builds use same debug signing config. 2) all but 1 release flavour use same release config. 3) a single release flavour uses a different key?

Comment: 1) All debug builds use same debug signing config. 2) All release builds can use different release signing configs as specified in product flavor. 3) Release builds can use default release signing config if nothing is specified in its product flavor.

Comment: Can you show how that code would look by updating your answer please?

Comment: How do you specify which productFlavor to assemble with gradle?

Comment: @DavidNathan You can specify that in Android Studio's left sidebar, under Build Variants, select the required product-flavor-releaseType for your module.

Comment: @Ashwin, thanks but I don't use android studio. For anyone else wondering the same thing: gradle automatically understands the commands: `./gradlew assemble<flavor>Release` etc.

So to assemble the product flavor `myFlav` using the release config, you need to run `./gradlew assembleMyFlavRelease`.

Comment: @DavidNathan, yes, the gradle command would be `./gradlew <module-name>:assemble<flavor-name><build-type>`

Comment: Is it possible to provide custom key for internal app sharing with app bundle

Answer (score 2):

You would have to define the signingconfigs in your buildTypes. Add custom signing config to your debug build type or create a custom build type

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
             signingConfig signingConfigs.custom
        }
        custom {
            applicationIdSuffix ".custom"
             signingConfig signingConfigs.custom
        }
        release {
             signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
        }
}
```

Gradle would create flavor for each build type and depending on the buildType the flavor would use the respective signinconfig. With the above configuration of build type , lets consider "apple" flavor. Gradle would create the following build variants just for apple

- **appledebug**    --> custom signing config
- **applecustom**   --> custom signing config
- **applerelease**  --> release signing config

  You can select the respective build variant and run your application

Adding signing config to flavor

```
productFlavors {
    def customSigningConfig = signingConfigs.custom

    custom {
        ...
        signingConfig customSigningConfig
        ...
    }
```

You need to declare your signingConfigs before you declare your flavors.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64701

Comment: To emphasize: I have 118 flavors using the same key. I have 1 flavor using a different key. I would like to know how gradle can build release APK files for all 119 flavors with a single command.

Comment: 118 flavor seems a large number for flavors though

Comment: **119** and counting. `gradle build` would also build 119 unneeded debug APKs, and 118 unneeded custom APKs (since I only need 1 custom). Current build time is 1 1/2 hours. `gradle build` would be 4 1/2 hours. Not scaling very well.

Comment: what is the reason for 119 flavours, I am just thinking if there is an alternative way and avoid spending 1 1/2 on builds.

Comment: No no. We have a white-label app that is being rebranded many times over (and counting). Flavors work great. Builds happen in the background. This post is just about the specifics of streamlining the signing process due to one original app using a different key.

Comment: I have updated the post on how to set the signingconfig on a buildflavor

Comment: Have you tested that code, and gotten it to work? Try as I might, I can't get it to pick up the custom signing config.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure this will work, but I dont think you want to create a new build type. That would create a new build variant for every flavor.  When really you just want one flavor to override a "default config" :)

This code isnt tested but you should be able to do something along the lines of this:

```
signingConfigs {
    normal {
        storeFile file('key')
        storePassword "pass"
        keyAlias "alias"
        keyPassword "pass"
    }

    custom {
        storeFile file('custom_key')
        storePassword "pass"
        keyAlias "alias"
        keyPassword "pass"
    }
}

    /**
     *  defaultConfig is of type 'ProductFlavor'.
     *
     *  If we need to use a different signing key than the default,
     *  override it in the specific product flavor.
     */

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 123
        versionName '1.2.3'
        minSdkVersion 15

        def standardSigningConfig = signingConfigs.normal

        buildTypes{
            release {
               signingConfig standardSigningConfig 
               zipAlign true
               // ...
            }
            debug { 
               //not sure you need this node
            }  
        }
    }


productFlavors {

    def customConfig = signingConfigs.custom
    def standardSigningConfig = signingConfigs.normal

    apple {
        applicationId "demo.apple"
    }
    banana {
        applicationId "demo.banana"
    }
    custom {
        applicationId "custom.signed.app"
        signingConfig customConfig
    }
}
```

Reference:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-Flavor-Configuration

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link. It was quite a journey to get a workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

One idea could be to use project properties in order to determine if you should or not use your custom signinconfig.

```
if (project.hasProperty('custom')) {
    android.signingConfigs.release = customSigningConfig
} else {
    //should use the default
}
```

Then to build your custom flavor you run:

```
gradle assembleCustomRelease -Pcustom=true
```

Comment: But that call will only build your specific variant, which should hopefully only take few minutes, at most. It can also be scripted and/or integrated in your CI so it wont require any effort for you

Comment: Appreciated @arnaud, thanks. However this question seeks to find a way to override a `signingConfig` for a single flavor/variant in order to avoid the use of an extra command or script.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr go through "gradle.startParameter.taskNames" to look for the flavor and modify the variable.

I do this for test variants for the Vine app and it works out very nicely. You can also use this to make different dependencies compile without adding more flavor dimensions.

It would look something like this in your case.

```
            //root of buil.gradle OR probably inside buildTypes.release
            def signType = signingConfigs.normal;
            //You can put this inside builTypes.release or any task that executes becore
            def taskNames = gradle.startParameter.taskNames;
                taskNames.each { String name ->
                    if (name.contains("customFlavor")) {
                        signType = signingConfigs.custom
                    }
                }
            buildTypes{
                release {                   
                    signingConfig signType
                }
            }
```

Comment: When running `gradlew assembleRelease`, the `taskNames` only contains "assembleRelease" and not all the flavors. So this doesn't really do anything useful.

Comment: ^yea, that was just meant to be a place holder.

Comment: umm, let me see if you can find the current task name