# Android flavors signing not working as expected

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, code-signing

I need to sign a product flavor with an specific signing configuration. I found some reference here at stackoverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898611/gradle-signing-flavors-with-different-keys-on-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040494/signing-product-flavors-with-gradle). It is working for my release version of flavor, but not the debug one. I have this configuration in gradle:

```
...
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("../config/keystores/release_keystore")
        storePassword "mysecurepassword"
        keyAlias "myultrasecurealias"
        keyPassword "myreallysecurekeypassword"
    }

    debug {
        storeFile file("../config/keystores/debug.keystore")
        storePassword "mysecurepassword"
        keyAlias "myultrasecurealias"
        keyPassword "myreallysecurekeypassword"
    }

    other {
        storeFile file("../config/keystores/other")
        storePassword "mysecurepassword"
        keyAlias "myultrasecurealias"
        keyPassword "myreallysecurekeypassword"
    }
}

flavorDimensions "dim"

productFlavors {
    production {
        dimension "dim"
    }

    other {
        dimension "dim"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'        
        productFlavors.other.signingConfig signingConfigs.other
        productFlavors.production.signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    debug {
        productFlavors.other.signingConfig signingConfigs.other
        productFlavors.production.signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

This works pretty well for the flavor `otherRelease`. But my APK is not being sigined with `other` signing configuration when I use the build configuration `otherDebug`. 
The `release` version was signed correctly.

Does anyone knows why in debug mode the signing configuration is not being applied as configured?

Comment: _"But it's not working for otherDebug"_ Define what "it's not working" means.

Comment: Sorry, I guess it was not clear. It's not being signed with my ```other``` signing configuration as I have defined in ```productFlavors.other.signingConfig signingConfigs.other```. I will update my question.

Comment: And which keystore _does_ it get signed with? Or does it not get signed at all?

Comment: Is there a easy way to get the signing info? I didn't find any. What I did was changing my password to a invalid one, so ```release``` versions break with wrong password and ```debug``` assemble a valid APK. I also instaled the ```productionDebug``` in the device and I could replace it with ```otherDebug```, which means they have the same signing info (I didn't get any warning about differences in signing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured out what was wrong, thanks to @AllanHasegawa with his comment in another issue: [Signing product flavors with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040494/signing-product-flavors-with-gradle?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment75973679_35057525) . For short, I had to add `signingConfig null` inside `buildTypes` because Android adds some default signing configuration. Even though I was trying to override it. Complete example based on my question:

```
...
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("../config/keystores/release_keystore")
        storePassword "mysecurepassword"
        keyAlias "myultrasecurealias"
        keyPassword "myreallysecurekeypassword"
    }

    debug {
        storeFile file("../config/keystores/debug.keystore")
        storePassword "mysecurepassword"
        keyAlias "myultrasecurealias"
        keyPassword "myreallysecurekeypassword"
    }

    other {
        storeFile file("../config/keystores/other")
        storePassword "mysecurepassword"
        keyAlias "myultrasecurealias"
        keyPassword "myreallysecurekeypassword"
    }
}

flavorDimensions "dim"

productFlavors {
    production {
        dimension "dim"
    }

    other {
        dimension "dim"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        // this loop is a better implementation than my previous example
        productFlavors.all { flavor ->
                flavor.signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }        
        productFlavors.other.signingConfig signingConfigs.other
    }

    debug {
        signingConfig null
        // this loop is a better implementation than my previous example
        productFlavors.all { flavor ->
                flavor.signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        productFlavors.other.signingConfig signingConfigs.other
    }
}
```

Comment: You just saved me after 4 hours of trying around. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my 2 days trying.